# Dimension of linear complex-symplectic reduction

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry

Let $(V,\omega)$ be a finite-dimensional complex-symplectic vector space and $G$ be a complex reductive group acting linearly on $V$ by preserving $\omega$. Then, there is a moment map
$$\mu:V\to\mathfrak{g}^*,\quad\mu(v)(x)=\frac{1}{2}\omega(xv,v)\quad(v\in V,x\in\mathfrak{g}).$$
Consider the algebraic symplectic reduction
$$V_0 := \mu^{-1}(0)//G=\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{C}[\mu^{-1}(0)]^G.$$
Do all smooth points of $V_0$ have the same dimension?